# Can I version an Android app without involving gradle?

Tags: android, qt, gradle, ant

I have a `QtApp` on `android` which builds using `ant`. This is working fine.

**BUT ---->** To regularly update my app on google Playstore I need to increment the version number of the app. I found that gradle has a nice way to increment the version number. But I see that gradle pulls in a lot of other complexities. I want to keep this simple with ant as it is working.

- **Isn`t there a simple way to increment the version number using ant without indulging gradle ?**
- **Should I really consider switching from ant to gradle ? Are there many strong reasons of using gradle on android ?**

Comment: What about gradle is so difficult? All Android libraries can be fetched easily using gradle. The versioning is simple. So what's bad about using it? And why aren't you using the offical IDE Android Studio?

Comment: @Felix. As my app is built using Qt. Hence, I am using QtCreator. using Qt ant is the default. With gradle, I have to input the gradle wrapper, wrapper.properties, build.gradle & structure the code in sr/main. I got though all this. Also a version.properties & got the versioning working. Now my app is building an apk using gradle. But, I am using static C++ libs in my app which gradle does not pick up by default: hence the app crashes. I will fix that as well. But all this work only to get versioning going ?? Hence put up this question to check whether its really worth it.

Comment: Simply: Don't use Qt. Qt is fine for Desktop apps, but nobody would prefer Qt over Android Studio.

Comment: @NelsonP as Felix have wrote you below my answer, you won't achive auto-versioning by using gradle (by default) so just left it as is. But take in mind that new project you should probably start with using Android Studio to be able to use newest android ide features.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set `versionCode` & `versionName` in [manifest directly](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html). By
   the way gradle does same thing, it just merges your manifest with
   generation of additional fields according to `build.gradle` file
2. You should definetely use gradle, it has a lot of features in comparison with ant. Android Studio supports gradle fully, it is more customizable, more flexible, than ant. You could easily transfer project across your team, but with ant this could lead to a lot of headache with dependencies conflicts. So loading dependencies on a fly it's a gradle feature and it helps a lot. I haven't written more, because you can check all gradle features yourself. I've just given you a council

Comment: I already have `versionCode` & `versionName` in my manifest file. But how can I auto increment it with every build without using gradle ? Isnt it possible with ant ?

Comment: Even by using gradle in Android Studio you have to increment it manually. And that's fine. You don't want to increment it every time you build the Project.

Comment: ok. thanks for explanations until yet. what is the best way to auto-increment version code in android projects build ? Any suggestions ?